# laravel passing parameters from view to route

Tags: laravel

Using a view with user input. I then want to pass to a route. This what I found so far: 
        href="{{URL::to('customers/single'$params')}}"

I want to pass the user input as the above $params to my route. This is sample of my route:

```
Route::get('customer/{id}', function($id) {
$customer = Customer::find($id);
return View::make('customers/single')
->with('customer', $customer);
```

As soon as I can pass the parameter I can do what I want with the route, which I know how.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Can you edit your question and add the code of your view?

Answer (score 3):

Basically you can pass parameter to routes by doing:

```
Route::get('user/{name}', function($name)
{
    //
})
->where('name', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

In your anchor tag, instead of doing href={{URL...}}, do something like:

```
{{ URL::to('user/$param') }}
```

For more information on routing, visit [link](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have and works:

```
    <a <button type="button"  class="buttonSmall" id="customerView"     href="{{URL::to('customer',array('id'=>'abf'))}}" >View</button></a>
```

But I need the array value 'abf' to be the value of a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in my view anchor tag

```
href="{{ URL::to('user/'.$param) }}"
```

instead of what was specified above

```
href="{{ URL::to('user/$param') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user it in View as I used:

```
<a class="stocks_list" href="/profile/{{ Auth::user()->username }}">Profile</a>
```

Hope it helps you.